# I need to determine a proper formula to get given values

Tags: trigonometry

I have some geographical heading data and I am trying to get some values off them.

suppose 
when the heading is 180 i need to get ~30
when the heading is 90 i need to get ~45
when the heading is 0 i need to get ~60

(e.g f(180) ~= 30, f(0) ~=60 )
so the result range is [30,60]

the results can be decimal or degree doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $f(x)=60-x/6$

f(0)=60

f(90)=45

f(180)=30